# How can I have an autoscroll down screen triggered when I hover over a certain div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, frontend

What I've been trying is this:

```
<a href="#link1">Take me to Link 1</a>
<a id="link1">Link 1</a>
```

Which works pretty well, with a click and I've been trying to change it to a mouseover with this little js:

```
$("a").hover(function() {
$(this).click();
});
```

But I can't seem to get it.  Is there another smoother way to do this perhaps using Jquery?   Thanks everyone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why your code isn't working. Anyway, this works using jQuery scrollTop:
http://jsfiddle.net/Tk5fR/

**JavaScript:**

```
$('a').hover(function(e){
    $(document).scrollTop($($(this).attr('href')).offset().top);
});
```

Comment: I see that yours works on jsfiddle, but yeah for some reason none of it is going through on my end.  I have this version of jquery `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>`
and the scroll works when I click the link.  Very strange.  Well anyways, thanks for ur help/

Comment: Share your website if you want, maybe someone's able to help.